# Can not write to excel file using JexcelAPI

Tags: java, jexcelapi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*;
import jxl.write.Number.*;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class reader {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,  WriteException, BiffException {
String inputFile = "C:\\Users\\Chemeris\\Documents\\Book1.xls";
File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
//Ading a label
Label label = new Label(2,2, "Hello");
sheet.addCell(label);
w.write();
w.close();
}  
}
```

I get a cannot find symbol error on ".addCell" and on ".write".
If you can help me solve this problem or offer another solution to wrting to an existing excel file I would be most thankfull

Comment: What is about [WritableWorkbook](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html) ?

Comment: I don't know *jexcelapi*. Maybe try [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use ApachePOI to get the same result. There are bunch of documents https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/)